# catalogProductInfo Returning 0.00 price for an item with a configured price

Tags: magento-1.8

I am using the SOAP V2 API to pull back product information and the product in question has a price defined of 9.99 which is not returned with the item.  The clients magento has a bundle product (flagged as disabled) with no price, and the sku in question is a simple type which I am filtering on.

Why is the price of 9.99 not being returned with the simple item?  I am not sure what additional information to include but this works for other items.

Comment: Is this product a part of the bundle? or is it the bundle that isn't having its price returned?

Comment: The product is part of a bundle

Comment: Ok one last clarification question, sorry. So the product is in a bundle that is disabled, but when you try to retrieve the product on its own it fails to get the proper price? What happens if you enable the bundle? Are there any other products in this situation that work properly (in a bundle that is disabled but still return the proper price on their own)?

Comment: You are correct in your first assumption.  I did a bit more testing last night and found something strange.  Even a simple product, that is not configurable or part of a bundle, was returning no price on either the order item query or getting catalog info for that product.  I unfortunately cannot update the items in this catalog as this is a live magento site.